# Sending custom response from ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a string in a custom mediator in the inSequence . I want this string to be the final response from the esb . I want to sent this string back to the client as response.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

After adding what ever the string you have inside the custom mediator you can send the current payload back to the client using the following config.

```
 <header name="To" action="remove"/>
 <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
 <send/>
```

Comment: I am doing this 
**<inSequence>
<class name="MyMediator"/>
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
<send/>
</inSequence>**

Inside MyMediator , i do this
**PayloadHelper.setTextPayload(synCtx, Mystring);**

But i am not getting any Response ! please help me on it

Comment: If you want to set a custom payload, then you should use Payload Factory Mediator.